# Is there a simpler way to get multiple random values in Java?

Tags: java, swing, random

I have created code to draw a random Oval with a random color and coordinate in a random part of a section of a plane that I have provided in swing every time my loop runs. Is there a simpler way to get these random values for the oval and if so what is it? Here is the code that I am using:

```java
for(int i = 0; i <= 200; i++) {
            double r = Math.random();
            int k = (int)(r * 255);
            double s = Math.random();
            int l = (int)(s * 255);
            double t = Math.random();
            int m = (int)(t * 255);
            g2d.setColor(new Color(k, l, m));
            double p = Math.random();
            int o = (int)(p * 550);
            double x = Math.random();
            int y = (int)(x * 500);
            g2d.fillOval(250 + o, 250 + y, 30, 30);
        }
```

Comment: There's many ways to change this, which ones of them are "simpler" really depends on what you want. 1. you can put each random number calculation in a single line and get rid of half your variables (namely the `double` ones). 2. you could put each of those calculations *directly* in the places where you use them and get rid of the other half of your variables (the `int` ones). 3. you could extract the whole idea of "get an integer number between 0 and `x`" into a method and just call that .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i <= 200; i++) {
    g2d.setColor(new Color(random.nextInt(255), random.nextInt(255), random.nextInt(255)));
    g2d.fillOval(250 + random.nextInt(550), 250 + random.nextInt(500), 30, 30);
}
```

Comment: p can be removed, its never used